# How to integrate Trac with TortoiseGit IssueTracker Integration/Config

Tags: trac, bug-tracking, tortoisegit

Is it possible to add Trac to TortoiseGit issue Tracker Integration? 
Are there any steps similar to TortoiseSVN?

I am unable to link the Trac server to TortoiseGit properly, So when I click on "choose ticket" button in commit window, It gives me an error "cannot find server Information".

[image]
[image]

I have "**tracexplorer.tsvntrac.tracprovider**" installed in my desktop

Comment: Are you referring to the [bugtraq properties](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TortoiseSvn)?

Comment: I have updated my Question. Is there a way possible to achieve to get ticket information from bugtraq properties? <<< I am unable to add Trac server from Options button of "Configure Issue tracker Information" window. I am manually editing and adding the server URL in parameters>>